# List display modes - list & tile

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend, markup

I am confused about the correct approach at solving the following problem:

- Having a list with picture, title, tags and icons in it
- Two buttons that should switch the display of that list
- Working with Bootstrap and jQuery

Ex:

```
<div class="display__list">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-2">Image 1</div>
     <div class="col-6">Title 2</div>
     <div class="col-4">Icons 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">Image 2</div>
      <div class="col-6">Title 2</div>
      <div class="col-4">Icons 2</div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">Image 3</div>
    <div class="col-6">Title 3</div>
    <div class="col-4">Icons 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```
<div class="display__tile">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">Title 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Image 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Icons 1</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-4">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">Title 2</div>
     <div class="col-6">Image 2</div>
     <div class="col-6">Icons 2</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-4">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">Title 3</div>
     <div class="col-6">Image 3</div>
     <div class="col-6">Icons 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far, my approaches would be:

1. One central class change that will affect the styling of the children.
2. Using data--class--tile & data--class--list attributes with the class names.
3. Defining both markup lists and show/hide regarding.

Only the third approach would solve the markup order issue. I would like to avoid duplicate markup and would prefer one list that behaves like needed. Any further help - confirmation would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  This question reads as too broad at the moment.

Comment: I would recommend option 1. Definitely not 3. Any option will require CSS though, can you provide us what you have done?

Comment: @Taplar: the question is if there is any other option except of the ones proposed by me? If not, how to solve that issue of changing markup/styling of the two list dynamically?

Comment: That's not a specific question.  That's a very broad question.  I was suggest you take a moment to review [ask] for details about the kinds of questions that we look for on the site.

Comment: @Taplar : Here is your QUESTION: How to change the markup of a one and the same list content to achieve 2 separate display - tile and list in Bootstrap 4 without duplicate markup definition?